# How can I select a previous sibling in CSS using the following sibling class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector, siblings

I am trying to select a previous sibling in CSS using the class name of its following sibling and I am struggling to figure it out. My objective is to remove the `bottom-margin` from the `title` element via the `h1-no-margin` class

```css
body,
html,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.container h1.title {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- I cannot edit the HTML for the container class -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- I cannot edit the HTML for the title class-->
  <h1 class="title">This is a title</h1>
  <!-- I can edit the HTML for the below div, so I can add and remove classes on it -->
  <div class="info h1-no-margin"></div>
</div>
```

.

Few things to note:

- I don't have access to any JavaScript
- I don't have access to certain parts of the HTML
- I haven't had any success on other solutions presented on SO

Here is the HTML:

```html
<!-- I cannot edit the HTML for the container class -->
<div class="container"> 
  <!-- I cannot edit the HTML for the title class-->
  <h1 class="title">This is a title</h1>
  <!-- I can edit the HTML for the below div, so I can add and remove classes on it -->
  <div class="info h1-no-margin"></div> 
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
body, html, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.container h1.title {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
```

The idea behind this is that I can use the `h1-no-margin` class on the div with the `info` class to add and remove the margin on different pages.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: No, it doesn't, hence why I asked the question @Byscripts

Comment: Use negative margin like this: `.h1-no-margin { margin-top: -2.5rem } `

Comment: In this instance, you can use negative margin to effectively hide h1.title's margin `.h1-no-margin { margin-top: -2.5rem; }`

Comment: have you tried setting a negative margin-top margin to *swallow* the bottom margin of the previous sibbling sitting on top ?

Comment: If someone didn't close the question then maybe one of you guys could have posted it as an answer as the suggested thread didn't have what I'm looking for

Comment: Unfortunately , previous sibbling or parent selector question get closed before any valuable answer can be given , sometines those *impossible* are not needed. I understand the frustration ..